# How to view an image from Linode Object Storage in browser?

Tags: html, node.js, aws-sdk, linode, aws-s3-client

My goal is to view an image from [Linode object storage](https://www.linode.com/docs/api/object-storage/) in browser (Chrome or Firefox).
When I was trying to open that file in Linode object storage using the displayed link I'm facing an error.

[image]

My linode object storage ACL is private. I try to open my images on browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution after digging AWS S3 bucket and Linode API document
This is fully working solution
https://dev.to/silver7tech/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-linode-storage-bucket-in-nodejs-backend-ok8

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your Linode **bucket**
2. Then on **Access**
3. Choose the best option (for you) from **Access Control List (ACL)** dropdown list.

Your can also disable the **CORS Enabled**. This one will grant access from all origins.